# Installed Ruby gems not in path on CentOS 7

Tags: ruby, centos7, rubygems

After installing a gem via `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc gemname` while sudo'ed via `sudo -s` it is not showing up in my path. If I drop privledges and go back to my user or if I `sudo su -` it shows up fine. Any idea what needs to be changed so that I can use the gem while sudo'ed with `-s`?

Comment: Your question has unclear grammar (lack of commas mainly).  Did you mean that you installed a gem as your non-root user, then while running as root (using sudo -s), the gem isn't in your path?

Comment: what is the difference in output of `echo $PATH` when your in via `sudo -s` vs `sudo su -`?